# Some data didn't save on firebase database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-realtime-database, backend, react-fullstack

I am asking for help in second time. I am making the burger app using the react platform and saving the data in the firebase database (realtime). When I am storing the data the price, address, customer information are saved on the firebase database but the ingredients variable didn't save on the database. how to solve this problem?

```
orderHandler = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();        
        this.setState({Loading: true});
       console.log(this.props.ingrediants);
        const order = {
            Ingrediants : this.props.ingrediants,
            Price : this.props.price,
            customers : {
                Name: 'Zulfiqar Hussain Anjum',
                address: {
                    street: '4',
                    zipcode: '46000', 
                    Country: 'Pakistan',
                },
                email: 'raeesanjum010@gmail.com'
            },
            deliveryMethod: 'fastest',
        }
        axios.post('/orders.json', order)
        .then(response=> {
            this.setState({Loading: false});
            this.props.history.push('/');
        })
        .catch(error=> {
            this.setState({Loading: false});
        });
    }
```

the link of firebase database and the database data is:

```
 baseURL : "https://burger-react-app-2faba.firebaseio.com/"

 orders
   -M2iPiluSayuzFdsfFNk
     Price: "6.500000000000001"
     customers
     deliveryMethod: "fastest"
```

Comment: `this.props.ingrediants` this would be the json values right ?

Comment: code seems fine, hardcode `this.props.ingrediants` values and then send the request.

Comment: `this.props.ingrediants` this value did not save and the rest of values will be saved on the database

Comment: i also have created the same app, for me it was saved properly on the database.